# Issue with moving folders in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, move, drag-and-drop

When I move folder by drag and drop to a higher level in the folder structure, sometimes the folder is moved completely, i.e. a "cut and paste" result. But sometimes it is moved to the upper folder as a shortcut to the old location. I can't find a pattern when the "shortcut situations" appear, it seems completely random for me.

Help! It is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I can reproduce your problem. We recommend that you don't use drag and drop but use "**Move To**".

[image]